# How to send a signal from arduino to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, arduino

I have used a load cell. Arduino is sending the load perfectly. When the load sensed by arduino crossess some value I want to send a simple signal to matlab. Then a MATLAB should capture the image. If someone has already worked on it please share how you have done it!.

Comment: Hi. I'd also try using a serial communication interface, for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [MATLAB Support Package for Arduino](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/arduino-matlab.html) or plain old serial communication. The former is pretty straightforward; see the documentation. Below is a *simple* example of how the latter would work.

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {  
  int load = getLoad();      
  if (Serial.available()) {  
    Serial.println(load);
  }
}
```

MATLAB:

```
% Connect to Arduino
s = serial('COM1', 'Baudrate', 9600, 'Parity', 'none', 'Databits', 8, 'Stopbits', 1);
fopen(s);
set(s, 'Timeout', 2000, 'Flowcontrol', 'none');
s.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';

% Read data from Arduino
load = fscanf(s, '%d');

% Close connection when done
fclose(s);
```

Check out the following resources for more details:

- ["Arduino Serial Data Acquisition" by Ye Cheng on MATLAB Central File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46775-arduino-serial-data-acquisition/content/readArduinoSerial.m)
- ["Arduino and Matlab: let them talk using serial communication!" by gianluca88 on Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-and-Matlab-let-them-talk-using-serial-comm/)
- ["How To Send Data From The Arduino To MATLAB" by Miguel on AllAboutEE](http://allaboutee.com/2011/07/04/how-to-send-data-from-the-arduino-to-matlab/)
- ["How can I communicate from Arduino to MATLAB" by Bill Nace on Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/140/how-can-i-communicate-from-arduino-to-matlab)
- ["Getting Started with Serial I/O" in the MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/getting-started-with-serial-i-o.html)
- ["Write and Read Data" in the MATLAB Documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/writing-and-reading-data.html)
- [matlabarduino.org](http://www.matlabarduino.org/)

Comment: Thank you mbaytas. Does your code work with all types of arduino ?

Comment: The general idea is the same, not only for all types of Arduino, but other devices that communicate over a serial port as well. I suggest you take a moment to look at the resources I posted above, because they cover a lot of implementation details which can make your life easier.